# LocalizedTextUtil memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, struts2

I have a memory leak in a java web project, use Struts2 (2.3.15.1) + spring (3.0.6), that is a production server, after about a week, the heap is almost 100%, and I use MAT to analyze the heap dump, I found that a large amount of Struts2 i18n resources exist in a `ConcurrentHashMap` of `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil`, see the screenshot below

[image: Issue Image]

I am a newer with MAT, but I think `GC` should have collected the useless struts `i18n` resources, and I tried that in my local, through JProfiler, I found that when a new request coming, some new `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil` instance will be created, and sometime later, they will be garbaged when GC run, I don't know what's wrong with the production server, in what case the `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil` instance will not be garbaged,

can someone provide me a suggestion?

Comment: Can you upgrade to latest S2 version?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the product server use OpenJDK from amazon, and we have another product server use JDK from Oracle and it works fine, so I prefer to try to upgrade JDK first, and if it still doesn't works, will try your suggestion, anyway, thanks a lot!